# Stackoverflow-Exception while loading RelationshipEntity in OGM

Tags: java, neo4j, relationship, stack-overflow, neo4j-ogm

I have the following classes:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Item{
  //...
}

@RelationshipEntity(type = "HAS")
public class HasRelation{
  //...
  @StartNode
  private User user;

  @EndNode
  private Item item;
}

@NodeEntity
public class User{
  //...
  @Relationship(type="HAS")
  private Set<HasRelation> has;
}
```

So now I have a User `Sven` with ID 1 having an Item `Hammer` in the Database and want to load it.
When I call the OGM `session.load(User.class, 1)` I always get an Stackoverflow-Exception, because the User hold a Relationship, holding the User, holding a relationship, and so on.
This feels like the wrong way to use OGM for me and I don't want to restrict the Depth by which I load to 0.
However the OGM specification tells me, that there is no other way, since the RelationshipEntity needs a Start- and EndNode and has to be referenced in one of those.
So I don't see a way to prevent this Exception other than resticting the Loading-Depth to 0.
Is there a better way?

Comment: Please check if you have also a property set in the `RelationshipEntity`. This is also mandatory.

Comment: The `RelationshipEntity` has several properties. I just ommitted them for better readability.

Comment: Which version of OGM are you using? I will try to reproduce it.

Comment: I use ogm 3.0.2. Thank you for the effort

Comment: I have tried to reproduce this but it is working for me. If you can provide a complete, small sample of your bug on e.g. GitHub I will take another look at this.

Comment: I have set up a small example on https://github.com/Urr4/demo. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exposing the data as JSON. The converter also needs to traverse the 
'object tree' and this causes the stackoverflow.

The solution is simple: You are defining an outgoing relationship in the `User` class so this object does not need to be visited again when the jackson lib hits the relationship.

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "LIKES")
public class LikedBook {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String how;

@StartNode
@JsonIgnore // <- "do not go back"
private User user;

@EndNode
private Book book;
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I would never have guessed that the problem lies within the JSON Conversion. Thank you VERY much!